# Obtener coordenadas (x,y) de un svg e insertar una etiqueta text con un value

Tags: reactjs, svg

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación web con **React** para escribir tablaturas de guitarra, las tablaturas las estoy haciendo con **SVG**. Creo saber como obtener las coordenadas pero no sabría como insertar la etiqueta **text** con un valor ya que esta no tiene un atributo value donde pasarle el valor (o eso creo).

la funcion que tengo es:

```
// No hace nada
//supongamos que quiero agregar un 2
const clicked = (evt) =>{
    const { currentTarget: svg, pageX, pageY } = evt
    const coords = svg.getBoundingClientRect()     //<---- Obtengo las coordenadas 
const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text') //<--Creo el svg
    text.setAttribute('x', `$pageX - coords.x`) //<---seteo los atributos X e Y con las coordenadas del mouse 
    text.setAttribute('y', `$pagey - coords.y`)
    text.setAttribute('value', '2')            //<-------- Esto de acá no sirve
    svg.appendChild(text)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la funcion la saque de otro post para crear circulos con svg, seria la siguiente:

```
//Esta si sirve
clicked(evt) {
        const {currentTarget: svg, pageX, pageY} = evt;
        const coords = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
        const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        circle.setAttribute('cx', `${pageX - coords.x}`);
        circle.setAttribute('cy', `${pageY - coords.y}`);
        circle.setAttribute('r', '5');
        svg.appendChild(circle);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione agregando esto

```
const txtNode = document.createTextNode('2')
    text.appendChild(txtNode)
```

en lugar de esto `text.setAttribute('value', '2')`